# ¿Qué hacemos con las traducciones automáticas?

Tags: discusión, traducciones-de-contenido

He reportado esta respuesta por baja calidad, porque me parece (tal vez me equivoque) de que está traducida con algún servicio de traducción estadístico automatizado:

https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/611/74

¿Qué deberíamos hacer con este tipo de aportaciones? Me he mostrado a favor de traducir contenido (y más si es de calidad, tanto la pregunta como la respuesta) pero poner traducciones automáticas me parece muy negativo, porque creo que es lo contrario de lo que se busca en este sitio.

Comment: La verdad es que a mí me chocó también cuando la vi y la cambié (antes incluso de leer esta pregunta).

Comment: Si el aporte es bueno para el sitio, lo mejor seria editar la pregunta o respuesta y corregir los errores de traducción, justo lo que hizo @AlvaroMontoro

Comment: He buscado por el origen del texto/código y no lo encuentro... le preguntaré al autor sí es una tradu de una Q&A o una Q&A original suya que él ha pasado por google translate... es un colega de SOpt y obviamente su dominio de español es casi ninguno...

Comment: *(si, es texto original suyo y recién empieza a usar español en su trabajo)*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lo mismo que con todas las preguntas/respuestas de mala calidad, sean o no traducciones.

-1 y comentario sugiriendo mejoras si está ligeramente mal. Si se atiende +2.

Si es insalvable marcar para atención de moderador.

Answer (score 2):

Creo que puede haber 2 tipos de preguntas de esa naturaleza, de hablantes de otras lenguas que hacen preguntas aquí:

- ni con nuestros mejores esfuerzos es posible entender de qué trata la pregunta: votar para cerrar o reportar como "**no está claro lo que se pregunta**" *****; y, si posible, hacer un comentario pidiendo clarificaciones;
- es posible entender lo que se pregunta y parece útil: **editar** y dejar el texto claro.

En cualquier caso, votar + o - 1 conforme juzguemos necesario.

***** <sup>hay una corriente que defiende intentar clarificar primero antes de votar para cerrar, y otra que defiende el cierre rápido para evitar respuestas equivocadas/apresuradas. *Take your pick*.</sup>